# Fewest operations on an algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, algorithms, computer-science

I'm very stumped on this problem I have and was wondering if anyone could lend me a hand here?

Suppose that you have two different algorithms for solving a problem. To solve a problem of size $n$, the first algorithm uses exactly $(n^2)(2^n)$ operations and the second algorithm uses exactly $n!$ operations. As $n$ grows, which algorithm uses fewer operations?

Comment: The first one uses fewer operations.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge 3$ we have $n! \ge n^2 2^n$.

Indeed, let's try a proof by induction:
$$
(n+1)! = (n+1)n! \ge (n+1) n^2 2^n
$$
When do we have $(n+1) n^2 2^n \ge (n+1)^2 2^{n+1}$ so that we can complete the induction step?

This simplifies to $n^2 \ge 2(n+1)$, which holds iff $n\ge3$.

Comment: could you elaborate more on this? I am having the same problem as Jason, but I am not entirely following your answer to the question. From the very start, how do we have that for $n>=3$ we have $n!>=n^2 2^n$?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic, start from the bottom of the answer and go up

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not following? Where did $n^2>=2(n+1)$ even come from?

Answer (score 1):

We will now attempt to show for sufficiently large $n$, $n^22^n<n!$

$n!=1\times2\times3\times4\times5\times\dots\times n\\
=1\times3\times4\times5\times\dots\times(n-2)\times\left((n-1)\times2\times n\right)\\
>1\times3\times4\times5\times\dots\times(n-2)\times n^2\quad\text{since $2(n-1)>n$  for sufficiently large $n$}\\
>1\times2\times2^2\times2^2\times2^2\times7\times8\times\dots\times(n-2)\times n^2\\
>2^nn^2\quad\text{since $7, 8,\dots,(n-2)>2$}$